# Handling Endless Recursion in saveEntry?

Tags: plugin-development, entry, events

I'm trying to update the expiry field—based on an existing field (in this case `classDate`)—as soon as an entry is saved.

Based on [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/auto-expire-on-entries), the clever recursion code in carlcs' [Auto Expire](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-autoexpire/blob/master/autoexpire/AutoExpirePlugin.php#L61) plugin, I was able to get it working with this code:

```
public function init()
{

craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];

    if ($entry->section->name == "Classes")
    {
        $entry->expiryDate = $entry->classDate;

        static $recursionLevel = 0;

        if ($recursionLevel == 0)
         {
            $recursionLevel++;
            $saved =   craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
         }

    }


});
}
```

But that seems a little dirty because `saveEntry` is going to get called again.

Is there a better way to handle the recursion? [Bob's answer here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10271/updating-an-entry-after-an-event-action-within-onsaveentry) leads me to believe you can call `craft()->elements->saveElement` which won't raise the `saveEntry` event again but I couldn't get that to work.

What am I missing? Seems too easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's any less dirty, but another way you could do it would be:

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event)
    {
        $entry = $event->params['entry'];

        if ($entry->section->name == "Classes")
        {
            craft()->db->createCommand()->update(
                'entries',
                array('expiryDate' => DateTimeHelper::formatTimeForDb($entry->classDate)),
                array('id' => $entry->id)
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, db->createCommand-update... never thought about hitting the db "directly" but I like the idea! Simple. It works but the expiryDate is not matching up with the classDate.  Looks like the db stores in UTC? I got it to work by doing  ``array('expiryDate' => DateTimeHelper::formatTimeForDb($entry->classDate))`` not sure if there's a better way?

Comment: Nope, that's the way to do it... I'l update the answer.